# What type of chart is this?

Tags: data-visualization

I have tried different search queries in google but could not find an answer. What type of chart is this?

[image: Unkown chart type]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a [chord diagram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_diagram?wprov=sfla1) or radial network diagram.

Comment: Here an [example](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/) in d3.js.

Comment: +1 Now that we have a name for it, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14599150/4089351) provides some R code.

Answer (score 3):

It's a circos plot, see [here](http://circos.ca/).

Comment: I believe circos is a tool to generate chord diagrams; thank you for the answer. http://www.datavizcatalogue.com/methods/chord_diagram.html